# In kotlin how to create profile image and show first letter of contact name as a profile image in offline SMS app?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have to create offline app and I want to attach the profile image along the contact name and place the first letter of the as the profile image.But I do not understand how to code this.[image: **Screenshot of the running app on mobile.**]

I have searched but found nothing.

1.

```
class Inbox : AppCompatActivity(){

    private val requestReceiveSms: Int =1
    private val requestReadSms: Int = 2

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.readsms)

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS),
                requestReadSms
            )
        } else {
            refreshSmsInbox()
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>,
                                            grantResults: IntArray) {
        if(requestCode == requestReadSms) refreshSmsInbox()
    }

private fun refreshSmsInbox() {

        val smsList = ArrayList<SmsData>()

        val cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null,null,null,null)

        if(cursor!!.moveToFirst()){

            val nameID = cursor.getColumnIndex("address")

            val messageID = cursor.getColumnIndex("body")

            val dateID = cursor.getColumnIndex("date")

            do{

                val dateString = cursor.getString(dateID)

                smsList.add(SmsData(cursor.getString(nameID),cursor.getString(messageID),Date(dateString.toLong()).toString()))
            }while (cursor.moveToNext())

        }

        cursor.close()

        val  adapter = ListAdapter(this, smsList)

        sms_list_view.adapter = adapter
    }


}
```

**XML FILE**

2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView

        android:id="@+id/sms_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Expected**

Profile image along with contact name.

**Actual Result**

Just contact name.

Comment: 1. Don't use a ListView, it becomes hard to manage future features. 2. You can create a text view with a circle drawable as its background

Comment: Should I use then what to arrange contact list vertical?

Comment: Should I use layout of type of vertical?

Comment: @Ahmad Tell me please

Answer (score 2):

You can place a `TextView` in the ListView's item layout. Now we set a circular coloured background to this `TextView`. First, we define a background `drawable` for our TextView,

**profile_background.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

We set this background to a `TextView` in the ListView's item layout.

**listview_item_layout.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_text"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sample"
    />
```

Now, we need to set the first letter of the `nameId` to this `TextView`,

```
val firstLetter = nameId.subString( 0 , 1 ).toUpperCase()
profile_text.text = firstLetter
```

Comment: where we will place the firstLetter variable.In under  `if(cursor!!.moveToFirst())` or `do` condition..?

Comment: In the `SmsData` object, you need to create one more field which could store the `firstLetter`. So, the constructor of the `SmsData` should also have `firstLetter : String` as an argument.

Comment: I have done everything according to your code.In `val firstLetter = nameId.subString(0,1).toUpperCase()` , there is no `nameId` as my app is offline.I have tried `nameID` from the code but it show error.Then I tried `"address"` but it required `subString` function